# Error while calling ui function inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a hard time trying to call functions from inside other functions:

```
$('#edit_wgt_contact_form').modal();
//Widgets creation
function createWidget(type){
    $('#edit_wgt_contact_form').modal();
}
```

The first call to "$('#edit_wgt_contact_form').modal()" works as expected but the one inside the function returns an error "$("#edit_wgt_contact_form").modal is not a function".

(of course the createWidget function is being called in other part of the script).

This is just an example, I'm having the same kind of problem in different parts of my application and I just can't figure out what's going on.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the createWidget() function is called after the js plugin script containing modal() method is loaded?

Comment: Try to call the createWidget function into a $(document).ready() to be sure

Comment: This is just a snippet of the code, everything is inside a $(document).ready().
And yes, I'm pretty sure the plugin is loaded when the function is called because the first line works as expected.

Comment: The script for modal, or jQuery, is not being loaded before your function is being executed. Try Bouillou's method above.

Comment: As I said, the script is loaded properly. The main proof of it is that the first call to it works.

Comment: You're using jQueryUI correct? Are you sure you don't want the function .dialog() ? See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Qkmc/

Comment: I think your problem may be that your function modal is not defined correctly. Can you post the code where you define that function? And where it is relative to the function in the question. If it is declared `function modal(){ ...` it is treated differently than if it is declared `var modal = function(){...`

Comment: In fact, I'm not even using jquery-ui here. The modal I'm using is from Twitter bootstrap.
And I'm pretty sure it works correctly because the snippet above only throws an error for the calling inside the function. The other works as expected.

Comment: It seems like the `modal` function is disappearing at some point... perhaps you should log `$('#edit_wgt_contact_form').modal` at various points to see where it disappears?

Comment: @Brilliand, you're right. It happens because of double JQuery inclusion. I just posted and answer explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is due to the double inclusion of JQuery. The page from which this code comes from has an ajax call that loads another page and it includes JQuery once more.

This is a known bug as documented here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12136

Thanks for everybody that contributed!